# Alfa Wireless card monitor mode on kali linux

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

I have a wireless card (Alfa AWUS036H) that I use for pen-testing on my test network. Due to my recent interest in network hacking, I picked up this card and put it into monitor mode. While it scanned networks fine and picked up strong signals from neighboring networks, if I disconnected it or restarted my computer the next day, it would not discover any networks using the command airodump-ng wlan0mon wlan0mon being the interface of the card. To get the card to work again, I would have to restart the virtual box, unplug the device or even restart my computer multiple times to get it to work. I don't know if it is a software problem or a hardware issue. If this was a real-world situation this would in no way be practical. I run kali-linux 2019.1 on virtual-box 5.2. My computer runs on Windows 10. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the real world it is run from the HDD as a physical OS.

The command to start & stop using :

`airmon-ng stop wlan0` &
`airmon-ng start wlan0`

**wlan0mon** is the virtual interface created from physical interface **wlan0**

Don't call on virtual interfaces with airmon-ng you will get buggy results at best. airmon-ng **creates** the virtual interface...

Comment: I use that to set he card into monitor mode and it works without problems. The problem I have is that when I run airodump-ng It only works sometimes. As in one time I will start the box put the card into monitor mode then start airpdump-ng and it picks up and scans networks fine. Other times no networks are detected with airodump-ng.

Comment: 1. Why are you trying this from a virtual machine?  2. I haven't had good experiences with realtek chipsets & Kali Linux, But it wasn't as bad as you are describing. I'm assuming the virtual machine is what's causing 50% of the buggyness. Get something with an Atheros chipset, they do not have these issues.

Comment: I tried using kali Linux from live USB but my keyboard doesn’t work. Pls help

Comment: Desktop or laptop?

Comment: It’s a laptop ;)

Comment: Have you tried a USB keyboard? I have never seen Kali not recognize a keyboard to be perfectly honest. Does your laptop have a physical switch, or Fn + button combo to disable the keyboard? Pretty much any keyboard should work with the generic keyboard drivers. (But may not recognize laptop specific keys)

Comment: It’s a surface laptop maybe it’s special?  I’ll try the USB keyboard

Comment: Any luck with a USB keyboard?

Comment: Sorry for responding so late, yes the wireless USB keyboard works but I still need the original keyboard to work

Comment: No worries. This link may help you, or you may just want to keep an eye on the rolling releases of kali, I'm sure the drivers will make it into the kernel at some point. https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface

Comment: Let me know if you run into trouble. I'll try to help the best I can. https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I followed the instructions for Debian based systems and in step four:  checkout the version of the kernel you wish to target(replace with your target version)

Comment: I don’t quite understand that part